# can I use my developer certificate on multiple Mac?

Tags: ios, certificate

Can I use my same developer certificate in two Mac ? I usually use my certificate at my home but I need to use it at work as well. If I use it at my work, will the certificate work at my home pc as well ?? Getting bit confused !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes, you can use developer certificate in 2 macs or more macs.**

You have to do just 1 thing, Export certificate in .p12 from the mac where you created it and that's it. Install this .p12 file on any mac it works.

Answer (score 0):

Yes

[The following links discusses some items that would be useful for setting up additional environments.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-accounts_preferences/articles/export_signing_assets.html)